# Unable to trigger jenkins job through java code

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to trigger jenkins job through java code. I got the sourcecode online .I'm not able to made it to work . **I keep getting "server returned HTTP error code 403"**

Please find the sample code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JenkinsScraper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{


        try {
            URL url = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/job/SampleJob/build");
            String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin:admin").getBytes());

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in   = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I even tried to follow this [URL](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to trigger Jenkins job through command line but i'm just a beginner i don't understand.

Am i missing out anything here. Any advice on this would be helpful. Any working example would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the properties listed below and make the configuration change in Jenkins configuration.
Set up token with some value in the Jenkins configuration on the option "Trigger build remotely", use that value in the query parameter of Jenkins URL

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code working as expected:

 try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/job/TestPrj/build"); // Jenkins URL localhost:8080, job named 'test'
            String user = "username"; // username
            String pass = "jenkinsapitoken"; // password or API token
            String authStr = user + ":" + pass;
            String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authStr.getBytes("utf-8"));

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```